# Как найти i-ый элемент AVL за log()?

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, дерево, индексы

При изучении сбалансированных деревьев, столкнулся с проблемой - не могу написать/найти алгоритм, работающий быстрее, чем за O(N) для нахождения i-ого по возрастанию элемента дерева.

В сети есть много пояснения того, как надо сделать это в общем случае - взять размер левого поддерева и применить ряд операций, например, обсуждалось вот здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329171/find-kth-smallest-element-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-optimum-way/2329236#2329236

Однако везде рассмотрен общий случай и есть пояснение, что для сбалансированного дерева это можно сделать за логарифм.

Тут у меня и проблема - при повороте поддеревьев, я должен пересчитывать и размеры. Есть идеи, как это сделать, сохранив нужную асимптотику?

Вот фрагмент самой балансировки:

```
 private void rebalancing(Node node)
    {
        while (node != null)
        {
            updateNodeHeight(node);
            if (checkNodeHeight(node.left) >= 2 + checkNodeHeight(node.right))
            {
                if (checkNodeHeight(node.left.left) >= checkNodeHeight(node.left.right))
                {
                    rightRotation(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    leftRotation(node.left);
                    rightRotation(node);
                }
            }

            else if (checkNodeHeight(node.right) >= 2 + checkNodeHeight(node.left))
            {
                if (checkNodeHeight(node.right.right) >= checkNodeHeight(node.right.left))
                {
                    leftRotation(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    rightRotation(node.right);
                    leftRotation(node);
                } 
            }
            node = node.parent;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

При любых локальных операциях с деревьями (в том числе поворотах, переподвешиваниях и тому подобному), которые начинаются от корня дерева (т.е. вы не применяете операцию к произвольному узлу, не обновляя после этого весь путь от узла до корня), можно пересчитывать любые ассоциативные функции от поддеревьев (в том числе количество элементов, их сумму).

Делается это очень просто: заведите функцию, которая будет для заданной в качестве параметра вершины пересчитывать размер её поддерева в предположении, что для детей размер поддерева посчитан правильно. Дальше нужно лишь вызывать эту функцию для вершин, у которых поменялся какой-то из детей.

Добавим инвариант в программу: в каждой вершине корректно посчитан размер её поддерева. Этот инвариант будем требовать везде, кроме процедур поворота.
А при повороте по ребру вы лишь переподвешиваете как-то детей между вершиной и её родителем. В детях по-прежнему корректно посчитаны размеры поддеревьев, значит, вызывав перерасчёт для вершины и родителя (в нужном порядке - сначала у той, что стала ниже, а потом у другой) мы корректно обновим в них значения.

Это лишь константное число операций на каждый поворот что, очевидно, сохраняет асимптотику.